# Rails polymorphic association has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-inheritance, polymorphic-associations, single-table-inheritance

I want to create a sport statistic webpage where I can store different sport stats for each player. A player can have stats from different sports.

The way I was thinking of doing this is to create an overall Stat model that contains the basic attributes for every stat, regardless of the sport, such as place, date, opponent, etc. In this way, each sport that would inherit from the *Stat* model - such *FootballStat* and *BasketballStat*.

It seems that using Single Table Inheritance will prove to be very inefficient because every sport has very different statistics. Therefore, I only found two other options:

- Polymorphic association, and
- Multiple Table Inheritance.

Which one do you think will be more effective in this case? And how would go about implementing it?

---

This is what I am trying to do, maybe you can please help me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphic associations is surely the way to go. You can implement it as follows.

```
Class Stat 
  belongs_to :sportable, 
  belongs_to :player
end

Class Sport1
  has_many :stats, :as => :sportable
  # various attributes for sport1
end

Class Sport2
  has_many :stats, :as => :sportable
  # various attributes for sport2
end

Class Player
  has_many :stats
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. That looks much simpler than I thought. The only part I don't understand is where did you define the Sportable class and what exactly its function is? Thank you

Comment: sportable is not a class, its just a common name which you can use to call a parent sport class of stat. for example @stat.sportable will return the specific port class to which the stat belongs to. In your migration of stat class you need to add to fields namely 1) sportable_id 2) sportable_type. The sportable_type contains the name of class (eg. Sport1) to which Stat belongs.